# I'm trying to create a customize id or unique id like SID0000001, but there's an error: '(' , ')', <column constraint> or comma expected, got'+'

Tags: java, android-studio, android-sqlite

So this is were the error occur on `CON_SID + "AS 'SID' + RIGHT('000000' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(6)),6)PERSISTED);";`

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TBL_Name +
            " ("+ CON_ID + "INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
            CON_Name + " TEXT, " +
            CON_Address + " TEXT, " +
            CON_BDay + " TEXT, " +
            CON_Gender + " TEXT, " +
            CON_Course + " TEXT, " +
            CON_SID + "AS 'SID' + RIGHT('000000' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(6)),6)PERSISTED);";
    db.execSQL(query);
}
```

Comment: IDENTITY, RIGHT, PERSISTED none of them is supported by SQLite.

Comment: Do you know some other way to create an id like SID00001 (School ID).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use MYSQL's dialect of SQL. However, you could mimic the result by utilising a TRIGGER ***(not that you need to - explained below)*** for example :-

First create the table (names based upon your question) e.g. :-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS example (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    name TEXT, 
    address TEXT, 
    bday TEXT, 
    gender TEXT, 
    course TEXT, 
    sid TEXT UNIQUE
);
```

- note [AUTOINCREMENT](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html) dropped, see link

Then add the TRIGGER using :-

```
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS example_after_insert AFTER INSERT ON example 
BEGIN
    UPDATE example SET sid = 'SID'||substr('000000',1,6-length(id))||id WHERE id = new.id;
END
;
```

The SID would then be generated whenever a row is inserted. For example :-

```
/* INSERT rows where id column is generated by SQLite */
INSERT INTO example (name,address,bday,gender,course) VALUES
    ('name1','addr1','bday1','female','course1'),
    ('name2','addr2','bday2','male','course2'),
    ('name3','addr3','bday3','female','course3')
;
/* INSERT rows with specific ID's to test values */
INSERT INTO example (id,name,address,bday,gender,course) VALUES
    (15,'name1','addr1','bday1','female','course1'),
    (135,'name2','addr2','bday2','male','course2'),
    (1234,'name3','addr3','bday3','female','course3'),
    (98765,'name3','addr3','bday3','female','course3'),
    (999999,'name3','addr3','bday3','female','course3'),
    (9999999,'name3','addr3','bday3','female','course3') /* overflow */
;
```

Using `SELECT * FROM example;` then shows :-

[image]

**Not that you need to**

You could achieve the same result without the trigger by simply generating the column when needed.

- This approach would afford the following benefits

  - reduce the storage space required
  - reduce the processing required when inserting a row

    - no extra column
    - no trigger and update
    - no additional index conflict checking
  - conform better with normalisation (not duplicating data)

For example to get the same result without accessing the sid column (i.e. showing that it's not needed) you could use (the generated column has been named schoolID ):-

```
SELECT 
    id,
    name,
    address,
    bday,
    gender,
    course, 
    'SID'||substr('000000',1,6-length(id))||id AS schoolID 
FROM example;
```

The  result :-

[image]